# How can I make some themes usable only by admins?

Tags: themes, theme-options, multisite

I want to restrict certain themes so they can only be usable by the an admin. If I network a theme then everyone has access to it. How can I do this?

Comment: Could explain what you mean with »usable«? Especially how should widgets and nav menus work?

Answer (score 1):

Its built in that way so you can have themes only on specific blogs:

1. Disable the theme under Super Admin
   -> Themes.
2. Enable the theme for one site under
   Super Admin -> Edit the site you
   want. Look on the top right, there's
   a list of disabled themes.